# LoopBack Relationships

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

This is my first time dealing with a NoSQL form of database and I'm a little confused about "relationships" in document-oriented databases. I'm using LoopBack & AngularJS.

I have a model `page` that `has many` `page` as it's `children` (i.e. menu items and submenus).

A `page` model is as follows:

```
"properties": {
 "name": {
   "type": "string",
   "required": true
 },
 "slug": {
   "type": "string"
 },
 "link": {
   "type": "string"
 },
 "createdAt": {
   "type": "date",
   "required": true
 },
 "children": {
   "type": [
     "object"
   ]
 }
},
```

with

```
"relations": {
 "children": {
   "type": "hasMany",
   "model": "page",
   "foreignKey": "parentId"
 }
},
```

My confusion is that whenever I `explore` the LoopBack API, and then `get` the `parent` pages, I don't see the `children` property populated. But, doing a `get` to see the children of a parent (using the parent's `id`) turns out fine - I can see the `parentId` populated with it's parent.

My question is if this is normal when dealing with NoSQL/document-oriented databases, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes LoopBack queries are getting messy when its come to relationships and parallel queries.

I think this is simply a query issue in LoopBack.

As I realized this is like Parent Page object can have multiple Children page objects.

We can use following query statement to retrieve related parent page and children pages.

```
    app.models.Page.find({
            where: {
              parentId : 'yourPageId'
            },
            include: {
              relation: 'Children'
            }

          }, function (err, pages) {
            if (err) {
              cb(err);
            } else { 
              console.log("you will get related children pages alone with parent page")
              cb(null, pages);
            }
    });
```

Hope this will work...!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might be missing the other direction of the relationship.

You can do a [belongsTo relation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/BelongsTo-relations.html) in the children to specify that it belongs to a parent.

That should enable you to see both directions' methods in the explorer.

Also, the foreingKey `parentId` should be set on the children, not on the parent. I.e. leave foreignKey empty on the parent `relations` definition, and instead use it on the `children` relations definition.

So on one hand, in the model you will have inside the relations field:

```
 "children": {
   "type": "hasMany",
   "model": "page",
   "foreignKey": ""
 },
```

And also

```
"parent": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "page",
    "foreignKey": "parentId"
 },
```

plus any other relations you have.

I have tested this and it works, although I have used two different models for the relation instead of only one.

I.e. I use

`ModelA hasMany ModelB` and `ModelB belongsTo ModelA`

instead of

`ModelA hasMany ModelA` and `ModelA belongsTo ModelA`

Comment: Does that mean I will have to create a new model (like `childPage`) in order to do this? Because basically, both `page` as a parent and `page` as a children, are exactly the same models.

Comment: I don't know if using the same model will work, you need to try that out. But if it doesn't, then I think you will need to create a new model indeed. However, I think creating another model also has other advantages. Even though they are the same right now, what if they change in the future? Also, isn't it easier for filters and such?

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose when you want to get the page's "children" populated you need to specifically ask for it using:

```
Pages.find({})
  .populate('children')
  .exec(function(err, pages){
     //..
  })
```

Looking on LoopBack's page (http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Querying-related-models.html) there is something similar called "include", you should try doing:

```
Page.find({include:'children'}, function() {
  //...
});
```

Let me know if that worked!